# Webservice mock callout goes to the webservice original class and fails

Tags: apex, callout, webservicemock, mock

I am using a WebService callout, returning a string, and testing it; I am quite new to it.
The problem is in the Mock class. When I am debugging it, the response element is created, the string is associated and the response_element is inserted correctly in this way:

```
tO.AOResponse_element a_element = new tO.AOResponse_element();    
a_element.AOResult = 'http://www.google.com/archive';
System.debug('MOCK Set response: '+ a_element.AOResult);
response.put('response__x', a_element);
System.debug('MOCK Set response: '+ a_element);
```

But after this, the flows goes to the original class (not the mock) and when it returns from it, it gives an error attempting to de-reference a line object, and that line references to the original string to be returned in the non-mock class.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
response.put('response__x', a_element);
```

The correct key value is `response_x`, not `response__x`.

Comment: Many thanks. So if the program doesn't recognize that field, it goes in the original webservice class and fails, I guess.

Comment: @Franktrt Yes, if the response value doesn't match exactly, this would cause the problem.